# Asp.net Encryption and decrytpion

Tags: asp.net

For encryption and decryption I am using one of symmetric key algorithm and storing that symmetric key in web.config. Is this a right way? or any other way to securely store this key. In real time projects for SSN encrypt and Decrypt how it is done. Please let me know.

Thanks,
Raj4MS

Comment: Since the key is on your webserver, you will find that just password protecting it will also be sufficient. If your server is hosting HTTPS pages, you will find that your private key is password protected by Windows anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in the Web.config, but then you will hgave to encrypt the Web.config it self, reference here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx

Comment: But it can be decrypted using the Machine key. Very trivial when you are already logged on to the machine. I wrote a little app that can do that for you: http://renewalprojects.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=.NET%20Encrypted%20Configuration%20Viewer&referringTitle=Documentation